# How to resend a request for a recommendation on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I keep getting this message when I click on request a recommendation:

> You have already sent George a recommendation request for this position

How can I resend it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and had a success solving it by deleting the position from experience field and adding it again. Then I was able to send the recommendation request once again.

Answer (score -1):

You can't find the solution anywhere, but I found it by luck.

Login on your Linkedin profile and then go directly to this URL (change the last part to your username specifically):

https://www.linkedin.com/recs/give?senderId=WRITE-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE

This will give you a popup with your requested, pending recommendations!

Comment: 1) If you are still logged in on LinkedIn in your browser, you can even click the link in the answer (incorrect user name), and LinkedIn will redirect you to 'yourself'. 2) The popup will also show you pending request *to you* from others (actually, I only had one of those, so I could not strictly verify this answer)